# How to delete words with more than six letters in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a long list of dictionary words in notepad++ and I am looking to shorten the list by deleting all words above six character. Is there any way I can do this. I have tried using multi-line editing but clearly this doesn't work because the word are too many.

Comment: Would probably be easier just to run it through a Python script.

Comment: How exactly do I do that?

Comment: Do you know Python?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: just `sed -r '/.{6}/d' mylist.txt > newlist.txt`

Comment: I'm not really familiar with Python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the replace window using:

- Find what: .{6,1000}  *(6 to 1000 characters, or the number you want)*
- Replace with: *(leave empty)*
- Search mode : Regular expression

All lines more than 6 characters will be emptied

Then you can delete empty lines:

- Find what: `\n\n`
- Replace with: `\n`
- Search mode : *Extended (\n \r...)*

Comment: Totally worked, though can you please elaborate the "extended" mode part. I still have the empty lines

Comment: I've added an explanation for that part

Comment: Why doing 2 replacements when a single one is enough?

Comment: Yes, @Toto. When adding `\R` to the initial expression you don't need the second step.

Answer (score 2):

This one do the job:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.{6,}\R`
- Replace with: `EMPTY`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               : begining of line
  .{6,}         : 6 or more any character
  \R            : any kind of linebreak
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ctrl-h and tick regular expressions. 
Try finding: 
^[A-Z|a-z]{6,}$
and replace with blank

[image]